# Getting error: TS2307(TS) Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing, when I clicked on "Restore Package" option

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Getting error: TS2307(TS) Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing, when I clicked on "Restore Package" option on package.json file which is inside visual studio project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a package in your node_modules for angular, sometimes visual studio does not restore all the packages properly when you click restore (happens to me constantly). I tend to always use the command line for `npm` - much easier.

Open up the terminal in the root of your project (where the `package.json` file is) and write the command

```
npm install
```

Then try

```
ng build
```

let me know if that resolves it for you